# Sql Server like command

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql server and I was wondering if there was a way to use a like command to get information from a field where the first letters start with A through C. For instance say I have a column FIRST_NAME and a couple of values: ANTHONY, BILL, CHAD, MIKE, WILL. Would something like my code below pull back ANTHONY, BILL, CHAD or is this possible??

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE_NAME
 WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '[A-D%]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '[A-L]%'
```